# iPhone Keyboard Not Appearing For First Time After App Launch

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextfield, uikeyboard

In my app keyboard was not showing for first time after every app launch. After clicking `UITextField` once again only keyboard was appearing. But `UITextField` cursor will arrear for particular `textfield` if keyboard is not appearing.

Comment: are you tried in simulator or device

Comment: Hi Kavin. Your titles are not very readable, because they are not in the format the community prefers. Prefixing all of your questions with "homemade tags" such as `iOS Swift` does not make for a sentence that flows, and we'd rather you just used natural English. The [meta post is here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076), and there's similar material on the overall Stack Exchange meta site as well. Would you use this approach for your future questions, please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with transition timing which can cause these kind of problems if you want that your keyboard should be active automatically you can trigger that through your code best place will be **viewDidAppear** which makes sure ongoing view controller transitioning animations have already been completed.

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animate)
     textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Note: you can not trigger 2 transitions at the same time presenting a keyboard has a lower precedence will be dismiss automatically without noticing.